# I think there's a bug in your badge awarding

Tags: support, badges

In the gamedev site I have a gold badge for "Asked a question with 10,000 views". Yet none of the 3 questions I have asked there are anything close to 10,000 views. I appreciate the free badge :) but you might want to check how it got awarded.

Answer (score 2):

You currently have two gold badges:

[image]

Those badge requirements are as follows:

[image]

[image]

Both of which you've met the criteria with for [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46463/is-there-an-optimum-set-of-colors-for-10-players) question, as it currently has more than 100 favorites and more than 100 votes.

[image]

While you're well on your way to this badge:

[image]

You don't have it, **yet**.

Comment: Ok, now I see. It lists Famous Question in my badges under gamedev. But I think it is actually due to my getting it in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25836/what-is-the-best-c-interview-question - so it has cross listings but it's not clear the listing is across all sites.

Comment: And a funny postscript - that question has over 17K views, yet it was closed as not constructive :)

Comment: @DavidThielen Yeah, that happens. Popular != on topic, unfortunately (or maybe fortunately). We're able to keep high quality on these sites by keeping off topic stuff shutdown. Sometimes that means the interesting off topic stuff too :)